# Solr - Exact and Stem search on same text with highlights

Tags: search, solr, lucene, edismax

I am trying to perform exact and stemmed searches on text and get back "compiled" results.

Currently what I have:
There is text being stored in the stem field and it's copied into the quoted field. Stem queries and exact queries work on their respective fields. When I search for (problem only with and)

`"word1 word2" and/or word3`

which gives me the query

`stemmed:word3 &/or quote:"word1 word2`

What I get is results from the two fields respectively. With or, this is fine but with and, I get back two or more results back for the same text and each has different highlighting.

The question is: what's the best way to do stem/exact search on the same text (guessing multiple fields) and if I have the right approach, what's the best way to merge these and if solr can do it?

Thanks!!
Edit: I checked out edismax but fail to see how to use it properly. My results are in the comments of the answer suggesting it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check on the [Edismax Query Parser](http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/solr/The+Extended+DisMax+Query+Parser) which will allow you to define the fields and have the text being searched on all of them with variable boost.

Comment: I've looked at it but I'm not having too much luck. From what I understand of it, pf is the "phrase field" or quoted field. qf is the query fields that the query runs on. You use the boost on the qf (which is one of the fields of the pf) to eliminate any results that don't match the exact phrase. I'm using a slop of 2 and a boost of 10. The problem I keep facing is that my query keeps running the phrase portion of the search against the stemmed field.
Then the problem with highlight comes in. As I am searching on the same text, I don't want two fields returning.